# build issue after upgrading "react-native-fbsdk": "0.8.0", in android

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-android-sdk, react-native-fbsdk

In a React Native app, I am getting the following errors while running. Compiling is happening but while running, the app is having this error:

```
facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java:
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: could you add relevant parts of your build.gradle files

Comment: yes all is added